# LDAP connection error code {"Unknown error (0x80005000)"}

Tags: vb.net, ldap, directoryentry

```
Dim oEntry As DirectoryEntry
Dim path As String = "ldap://10.0.17.79:389/dc=maxcrc,dc=com"
Dim username As String = "cn=Manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com"
oEntry = New DirectoryEntry(path, username, "abc")
```

unable to connect to openLDAP server.

Comment: I'll not miss all those [near useless] COM errors :|

Answer (score 3):

Use `LDAP` instead of `ldap`

MSDN says

```
The section of the Path that identifies the provider (precedes "://") is 
case-sensitive. For example, `"LDAP://"`
```

---

```
Dim path As String = "LDAP://10.0.17.79:389/dc=maxcrc,dc=com"
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: No it is still not working. System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException' occurred in System.DirectoryServices.dll